# invoking an AWS lambda by API-GEATWAY doesnt wait for response 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-api-gateway

I am using Postman (HTTP) to invoke an AWS Lambda .

the response I received from Postman is

> 503 "Service Unavailable"

Although lambda successfully ends in the CloudWatch logs after 2 minutes,

The postman doesn't wait for the lambda to finish and returns 503 already.

how can I make the postmen wait for the response?
I tried to call this HTTP in jave code and this is showing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

AWS API Gateway has some limits, which you can explore on below link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-execution-service-limits-table

in your case its integration timeout, you will have to do Lambda processing in async way.

Hope this helps.